# sending jquery string via AJAX and saving it to html file using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send a string via AJAX to a PHP file. I have two lottery wheels, each of them has a result (if you press on "spin"). I wish to receive the results and print them to an HTML file. Please see here:
http://zeevm.co.il/rollet/

This is the AJAX code that is sending the first wheels result:

```
function sendwinnertophp(){
    var winner = $("#winner").html();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getwinner.php",
        data: {
            "winner": winner
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){ 
        //  alert(data);
        },
        error: function(err){
            alert(err);
        }
    });
}
```

This is the PHP code that is saving it to the HTML file:

```
$file = fopen("log.html", "a");
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$winner = $_POST['winner'];

//write the data
$time = date("H:i dS F");
fwrite($file, "<b>Time:</b> $time<br/><b>ip:</b> $ip<br/><b>score:</b> $winner<br/><hr/>" );

fclose( $file );
```

But, I have two wheels that each of them has its own result. I wish to duplicate the Ajax code so it will send the second wheel's result and print it to the HTML file using the PHP.

I have tried adding this after the first function:

```
function sendwinnertophp222(){
    var winner222 = $("#winner222").html();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getwinner.php",
        data: {
            "winner222": winner222
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){ 
        //  alert(data);
        },
        error: function(err){
            alert(err);
        }
    });
}
```

And this to the PHP file:

```
$file = fopen("log.html", "a");
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$winner = $_POST['winner'];
$winner222 = $_POST['winner222'];

//write the data
$time = date("H:i dS F");
fwrite($file, "<b>Time:</b> $time<br/><b>ip:</b> $ip<br/><b>score:</b> $winner<br/> $winner222<br/><hr/>" );

fclose( $file );
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: I see that your data in the ajax call is wrong. `data: {
            "winner222": winner222
        },`  The value is the one that should be around quotes, not the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Duplicating the same code twice you can simple increse the number of post variables :

```
function sendwinnertophp(){
    var winner = $("#winner").html();
    var winner_two = $("#winner222").html();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getwinner.php",
        data: {
            "winner": winner,
            "winner_two" : winner_two
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){ 
        //  alert(data);
        },
        error: function(err){
            alert(err);
        }
    });
}
```

And in PHP File :

```
$file = fopen("log.html", "a");
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$winner = $_POST['winner'];
$winner_two = $_POST['winner_two'];

//write the data
$time = date("H:i dS F");
fwrite($file, "<b>Time:</b> $time<br/><b>ip:</b> $ip<br/><b>score:</b> $winner<br/><hr/>" );
fwrite($file, "<b>Time:</b> $time<br/><b>ip:</b> $ip<br/><b>score:</b> $winner_two<br/><hr/>" );

fclose( $file );
```

Comment: thank you ! your code did the job. only one thing. it is duplicating the resaults in the log file. see here: http://zeevm.co.il/rollet/log.html
every time you press on "spin" it will show the resaults 4 times (insted of two)

Comment: If you check your network Panel you can see that there are two ajax request being called.

Comment: the log file is now cleared. i don't understand where are those two AJAX requests are coming from. if you look at the code, there is only one function with ajax in it